# Why does Microsoft SQL Server Allow Foreign Key Duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, duplicates

Consider the following script, which I ran in Microsoft SQL Server 2012:

```
create table PKTestTable1 (
    Column1 int not null,
    Column2 int not null,
    constraint PK_PKTestTable1 primary key (
        Column1,
        Column2
    )
)
create table FKTestTable1 (
    Column1 int not null,
    Column2 int not null
)
alter table FKTestTable1 add foreign key (Column1, Column2) references PKTestTable1(Column1, Column2)
alter table FKTestTable1 add foreign key (Column1, Column2) references PKTestTable1(Column1, Column2)
```

Previously, if I had asked SQL Server to "find me the foreign key that points columns A, B, and C in that order on Table1 to columns D, E, and F in that order on Table2," I would have expected no more than one row returned. When running this script, I would have expected SQL Server to display an error citing the duplication, but it does not. Instead, two foreign keys are created with distinct, auto-generated names. As far as I can tell, these foreign keys are exactly the same in every respect except for their names.

I realize I can avoid this by naming my constraints - that's not the problem. It's confusing to see that multiple foreign keys are allowed to exist with the exact same definition. My question is: why does SQL Server allow this?

Comment: The same way it allows you to create 2 tables with the same schema, or views with same definition, or stored procedures with the same code. There is nothing wrong with that. You should know about your database before asking SQL Server to do it.

Comment: And you can create duplicate indexes.   SQL is just going to do what you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

There are other properties that a foreign key can have. Off the to of my head, something like "on delete cascade". By allowing " duplicates", you can change your mind on what those properties should be. For example:

1. Foreign key already exists
2. Create new foreign key with "on delete cascade"
3. Drop old foreign key

In that scenario, your data is protected at all times by at least one foreign key.

Comment: I don't think that can be the whole story. If it were, wouldn't duplicate Primary Keys be allowed? What if I change my mind on the fill factor or the column ordering? Using your logic, it would make sense to create a new primary key with the updated requirements and delete the old one. Yet this is not allowed (I presume) because a primary key is uniquely defined by its columns and their ordering, not its properties. By extension, it makes sense for a foreign key to be uniquely defined by its columns, their ordering, and their referenced objects. Is there something wrong with my logic here?